# rhel 7.1 octave gnuplot - resolving libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast

Tags: opengl, gnuplot, octave, rhel

I have recently gone through a drill to resolve getting octave on rhel 7.1 to plot using gnuplot. Basically, I was getting the following ugly messages and no plot:

```
    $ export LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose
    $ octave
    $ GNU Octave, version 3.8.2
    octave:1> x = -10:0.1:10; plot(x, sin(x))
    libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib64/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so 
    libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib64/dri/swrast_dri.so
    libGL: driver does not expose __driDriverGetExtensions_swrast(): 
    /usr/lib64/dri/swrast_dri.so: undefined symbol: __driDriverGetExtensions_swrast
    libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/jsaari/.drirc: No such file or directory.
    libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/jsaari/.drirc: No such file or directory.
    libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
    function is no-op
    function is no-op        
    function is no-op
    . . .
```

Comment: You have a system with broken OpenGL. Perhaps you've installed the proprietary Nvidia driver which broke this?  Or you've not installed mesa DRI? Nevertheless this isn't a problem with GNU Octave and you should use for example `glxgears` to debug this and get OpenGL running before using the OpenGL backend in Octave

Answer (score 2):

I finally came to a resolution after not finding any singular helpful posting.

Apparently there are issues with the OpenGL/Mesa implementation. Also, octave had multiple graphics outputs available and USED to use gnuplot by default. This particular version of octave has "fltk" aka "OpenGL" as the default graphics output. This is easy to overcome by setting the graphics library default.

```
    octave:1> graphics_toolkit()
    ans = fltk
    octave:2> available_graphics_toolkits()
    ans =
    {
      [1,1] = fltk
      [1,2] = gnuplot
    }
    octave:3> graphics_toolkit("gnuplot")
    octave:4> graphics_toolkit()
    ans = gnuplot
    octave:5> x = -10:0.1:10; plot(x, sin(x))
```

which now gets me a nice plot.

If this saves somebody the two hours of my life I will never get back again, it was worth posting.